# how to secure audio source from other users using angularjs and sailsjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, sails.js

I'm developing e-store application for music(play and buy songs).I want to show songs for users and they can hear & buy. i need to hide songs URL from users. i'm using sailsjs as server and angularjs as frontend. so, how to do. help me.

Comment: Please post some code. "hide url from users" are you talking about your song's download url? Just don't send it to the client. If you need it to be unguessable, create a unique download token for each user/song and only download the song relating to that token/user.

Comment: Thanks for response. yes, i need to play songs only but not to be download that songs using showed URLs.